# Multiple memcache lookup Vs one lookup (with big output)

Tags: php, memcached

I am working on an application using memcache pool (5 servers) and some processing nodes. I have two different possible approaches and I was wondering if you guys have any comments on comparison based on performance (speed primarily) between the two

1. I extract a big chunk of data from memcache once per request, itereate over it and discard the bits I dont need for the particular request
2. I extract small small bits from memcached and only extract the ones I need. i.e. I extract value of a and based on value of a, extract value of either b or c. Use this combination to find the next key I want to extract.

The difference between the two is that the number of memcached lookups (which is a pool of servers) reduces in 1. but the size of response increases. Any benchmarking reports around it someone has seen before?

Unfortunately I cant use a better key based on request directly as I dont have enough memcache to support all possible combinations of values, so I got to construct some of it at run time

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to benchmark for your own setup. The parts that would matter wold be the time spent on:

- requesting large amount of data from memcache + retrieving it + extracting data from the resonse
- sending several requests to memcache + retrieving the data

Basically first thing you have to measure is how large the overhead for interaction with your cache pool is. And there is that small matter of how this whole thing will react when load increases. What might be **fast now**, can turn out to be a **terrible decision later**, when the users start pouring in.

This kinda depends on your definition of "large chunk". Are we talking megabytes here or an array with 100 keys? You also have to consider, that php still needs to process that information.

There are two things you can do at this point:

1. take a hard looks at how you are storing the information. Maybe you can cut it down to two small requests. One to retrieve the specific data for the conditions, and other to get the conditional information.
2. setup your own benchmark-thing for your server. Some random article on the web will not be relevant to *your* system architecture.

I know this is not the answer you wanted to hear, but that's my *two cents* .. here ya go.